# Python: Custom library with the same folder structure as the current library

Tags: python, import, module, package, dependencies

I have an issue with python and building a custom library that used another custom library.
Lets say library A is built under the folder structure src.custom.module.library_a.py.

Now, I want to build a library B with the folder structure: src.custom.library.library_b.py.

What I want is being able to call from src.custom.module import library_a but apparently my pycharm is saying that it cannot be found.

I am quite new in python, and probably I am missing some information, but I cannot found this solution.

Comment: put a dot before src, so you have `from .src.custom.module import library_a` or include your import folder to python path

Comment: Hi Sembei, it is not working with the .src
so basically inside my src.custom.module.library_A.py, it has not found the following line:
from src.custom.library.library_b import Library_B

library_b = Library_B()

But it is working ok if I deploy it! 
Many thanks in advance! It should be a pycharm error